# The constructor of type PaymentManager contains the parameter with name 'paymentMethods' and type List<IPaymentMethod> that is not registered

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am also getting the error below.  Is this because its not a List, and if so how do I correct this?

```
container.RegisterCollection<IPaymentMethod>(new[]
{
    typeof(AuthorizeNetProvider),
    typeof(StripeProvider),
    typeof(PayPalProProvider),
    typeof(PayPalStandardProvider),
    typeof(IntuitProvider),
    typeof(UsaEpayProvider),
    typeof(ITransactProvider),
    typeof(SecureNetProvider),
    typeof(ExposurePayProvider),
    typeof(PayTraceProvider),
    typeof(BraintreeProvider)
});
```

**Error**

> The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type IDivisionsService failed. The constructor of type PaymentManager contains the parameter with name 'paymentMethods' and type List<IPaymentMethod> that is not registered. Please ensure List<IPaymentMethod> is registered, or change the constructor of PaymentManager.

**Contructor**

```
public PaymentManager(List<IPaymentMethod> paymentMethods)
{
    _paymentMethods = paymentMethods;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List<T>` is [currently](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/545) not supported as collection type. Change the constructor to one of the following:

- `IEnumerable<T>`
- `IList<T>`
- `ICollection<T>`
- `IReadOnlyList<T>`
- `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`
- T[]

The first 5 types have the following behavior:

- They behave as *streams*, meaning that they resolve instances from the container, every time they are iterated.
- Because of this, they are injected themselves as singletons. Their instances, however, are still resolved according to their appropriate lifestyle.
- They are immutable. Trying to add, change or remove instances from `IList<T>` and `ICollection<T>` will fail with an exception.

The last type, the array, always represent a copy of instances and will not behave as a stream. Because it is a mutable list of instances, array is always injected as `Transient`, even though its list of dependencies all represent `Singleton` instances.