# The container can't be changed after the first call to GetInstance, GetAllInstances, Verify, and some calls of GetRegistration

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I cant figure out why I am getting this error below within the `RegisterCollection` method.  Am I doing the setup incorrectly?

> The container can't be changed after the first call to GetInstance, GetAllInstances, Verify, and some calls of GetRegistration. Please see https://simpleinjector.org/locked to understand why the container is locked. The following stack trace describes the location where the container was locked:

**Logger registration**

```
 public static void Register(Container container)
 {
     container.RegisterConditional(typeof(ILogger), 
        c => typeof(NLogLogger<>).MakeGenericType(
            c.Consumer?.ImplementationType ?? typeof(object)),
        Lifestyle.Transient, 
        c => true);

...

}
```

**container.RegisterCollection throws the error**

```
container.Register<IEmailTemplatesService>(() => new EmailTemplatesService(emailTemplates,
    container.GetInstance<IEventEmailTemplatesRepository>(),
    container.GetInstance<IEmailTemplatesRepository>(),
    container.GetInstance<IEventSettingsRepository>(),
    container.GetInstance<IEmailsService>(),
    container.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>(),
    container.GetInstance<IValidationProvider>()));

container.RegisterCollection<IStreamingMethod>(new List<IStreamingMethod>
{
    new CubeProvider(container.GetInstance<ILogger>()),
    new BallerTvProvider(container.GetInstance<ILogger>())
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are calling `GetInstance` during your container setup. As the exception and the referenced documentation explain, this is not allowed.

The problem is caused by you trying to partially hand-wire your registrations, while you should prefer letting Simple Injector do the heavy lifting and Auto-Wire everything for you. You should therefore change your registration to the following:

```
container.Register<IEmailTemplatesService, EmailTemplatesService>();

container.RegisterCollection<IStreamingMethod>(new[]
{
    typeof(CubeProvider),
    typeof(BallerTvProvider)
});
```

Comment: I did that but then I get the error in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50166383/implicty-way-to-do-simpleinjectors-registercollection-then-listing-all-types?noredirect=1#comment87367992_50166383